# Calculating percentiles by group in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Below is a sample data and I am looking for a solution to calculate percentiles (25th, 50th, 75th, 100th) for quantity sold grouped by country.

[image]

So basically add countries into different buckets from low, mid 1, mid 2 or high depending upon the unit_quantity. So if I create a table shown below in power bi, I want to create a calculated measure that adds the countries into these different buckets.

[image]

Currently, what I have tried is create 3 different quartiles in below dax measure and then using IF function i have tried to put them in different buckets :

```
Quartile = 
var FirstQ = 
    CALCULATE(
        PERCENTILE.INC('Sample Table'[unit_quantity], .25),
        ALLSELECTED('Sample Table')
    )
var SecondQ = 
    CALCULATE(
        PERCENTILE.INC('Sample Table'[unit_quantity], .5),
        ALLSELECTED('Sample Table')
    )
var ThirdQ = 
    CALCULATE(
        PERCENTILE.INC(Sample Table'[unit_quantity], .75),
        ALLSELECTED(Sample Table')
    )
var currentVal = SELECTEDVALUE(Sample Table'[unit_quantity])
return
 IF(currentVal <= FirstQ, "Low",
        IF(currentVal > FirstQ && currentVal <= SecondQ, "Mid",
            IF(currentVal > SecondQ && currentVal <= ThirdQ, "Mid 2", "High")
    )
)
```

But the above measure calculates quartiles for the complete table and not grouped by country. Also I want this to be dynamic since I am going to have a slicer for category column so the percentile values should dynamically change according to the category. I am very new to power BI so please bear with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PERCENTILEX` to run a table calculation, in this case, all countries.
I've added a condition of `ISFILTERED` to only display the results if the `country` field is present.

### Calculation

```
Quartile = 
VAR SelectedUnit =
    SUM ( 'Table'[unit_quantity] )
VAR p25 =
    PERCENTILEX.INC (
        ALLSELECTED ( 'Table'[country] ),
        CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[unit_quantity] ) ),
        0.25
    )
VAR p50 =
    PERCENTILEX.INC (
        ALLSELECTED ( 'Table'[country] ),
        CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[unit_quantity] ) ),
        0.5
    )
VAR p75 =
    PERCENTILEX.INC (
        ALLSELECTED ( 'Table'[country] ),
        CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[unit_quantity] ) ),
        0.75
    )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        ISFILTERED('Table'[country]),
        SelectedUnit <= p25, "Low",
        SelectedUnit > p25
            && SelectedUnit <= p50, "Mid",
        "High"
    )
```

### Output

| country | Unit Sum | Quartile |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bulgaria | 2 | Low |
| Canada | 83 | High |
| Croatia | 49 | Mid |
| India | 75 | High |
| Russia | 38 | Low |
| United States | 69 | High |

Comment: Hey Angelo. It runs like a charm with a little bit of modification. Thanks a lot for the solution.

Comment: The category slicer will be a local slicer to one of the table visuals but i have a use case where I have to add a global product_id slicer. It works perfectly fine with the category slicer but it produces wrong results when the global slicer product_id is being filtered. Is there any way to create it dynamic so that when the table is filtered by products, the buckets also dynamically change according to the unit_quantity?

Comment: Can you add a new question with the a sample dataset?

Comment: I might have framed the question in a confusing way but the use case that I am trying to create is very simple. I have a matrix which will have countries in Rows and unit_quantity in Values. When I filter it using the category column, it works fine since every country has unit_quantity value for all categories but filtering it through product_id column doesn't produce correct results since every product isnt sold in every country. I hope you are able to visualize it.